# What's the fastest way to download/select *all* documents from an Azure Cosmos DB collection

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have a collection of 10 million+ records and need to get them all as quickly as possible to load into memory.  Is there a way to do this faster than using query iterator?

This is my current code, I have 40,000 RU allocated but it doesn't seem to use all RUs available when I run my code.

```
using var queryIterator = container.GetItemQueryIterator<Customer>("select * from c");

var records = new Dictionary<string,Customer>();

while (queryIterator.HasMoreResults)
{
    var response = await queryIterator.ReadNextAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
     foreach (var customer in response.Resource)
     {
          records.Add(customer.Id, customer);
     }
}
```

Above code works but it takes a long time and I see my RU usage is only sitting around <10% of allocated.

Partition key of my documents is id, so all documents are in their own partition.  Would this be the reason for the slow read performance? Is there a way to speed it up?

I tried increasing the page size with QueryRequestOptions

`var options = new QueryRequestOptions { MaxItemCount = 10000 };`

But it didn't make much of a difference.  I think even if i set it higher it maxes to around 5000 odd documents per page.

Should I be running multiple queries in parallel since I have the RU headroom?

Comment: How you achieve this is really up to you, as there is no single "right" answer, but... keep in mind, RU/sec is your database throttle point (you'll throttle beyond 40,000 RU in a single second, with your settings). Does your *code* allow for thousands of documents per second? Have you benchmarked your code? If you're not hitting your RU throttle point, then it seems like you need to optimize how you're reading your documents. As an aside: seems like an odd requirement, reading 10s of millions of documents at once...

Comment: If you need to read all documents then using change feed processor (set to start from beginning) ensures that all physical partitions are worked. You may struggle to process the batches fast enough though to make much of a dent in your RU budget

Comment: Yes its an odd requirement because I was just using this as a way of testing that my migration from another database to cosmos db was successful by loading all documents and comparing them field by field.  It's a once off task but it takes 2+ hours.  Can't really use change feed for it, because it wouldn't be any faster and I don't care about the changes, i just care about the final document being the same as my old database.

Comment: Have a look at this lab, with diff settings for performance https://azurecosmosdb.github.io/labs/dotnet/labs/09-troubleshooting-performance.html

Comment: @lahsrah - change feed works fine for migration scenarios. It doesn't currently give you any information about the change anyway. It just gives you all documents ordered by `_ts` and is physical partition aware so distributes the work well over all physical partitions. Rather than potentially having some partitions using all their RU budget and others idle.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't an exact answer because it really depends on your application and resources.

You can start by fine tuning the concurrency by setting `MaxConcurrency` to either a calculated value or `-1`. Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/performance-tips-query-sdk?tabs=v3&pivots=programming-language-csharp#tune-the-degree-of-parallelism

You are already increasing the page size, you can fine tune the `MaxBufferedItemCount`.
Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/performance-tips-query-sdk?tabs=v3&pivots=programming-language-csharp#tune-the-buffer-size

Also keep in mind that it depends what you do with the responses, in your case you are just putting them in a Dictionary, but what if you put them in a construct that can already start consuming them (like a PubSub system), that way, the process that consumes the results can start to work while you fetch more pages.

Finally, you could even distribute this across multiple machines. Use `FeedRange`s:

```
IReadOnlyList<FeedRange> feedRanges = await container.GetFeedRanges();

// You can distribute each feedRange to a separate compute through feedRange.ToJsonString() and feedRange.FromJsonString()
// or start concurrent Tasks one per FeedRange if the machine is big enough

// per FeedRange, you can do:
using var queryIterator = container.GetItemQueryIterator<Customer>(feedRange, new QueryDefinition("select * from c"));

var records = new Dictionary<string,Customer>();

while (queryIterator.HasMoreResults)
{
    var response = await queryIterator.ReadNextAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
     foreach (var customer in response.Resource)
     {
          records.Add(customer.Id, customer);
     }
}
```